# BitBucket maven repository

Tags: maven, repository, bitbucket

I was asked to use Gradle in several projects and create a remote repository of various jar files that might be needed by the projects. 
I am new to Gradle but just defining the library dependencies does not seem something difficult. Now regarding the repository I would like to use Bitbucket as host of a Maven repository, following this guide [rapidminer_maven-repo Wiki](https://bitbucket.org/neil_rubens/rapidminer_maven-repo/wiki/Home). 
As I have not experience with Maven and I have spent too much time with this guide, could someone explane the steps in more detail to set this up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I followed in order to create a Maven repository hosted on bitbucket:

https://bitbucket.org/neil_rubens/rapidminer_maven-repo/wiki/Home  Guide I partially followed.

1. Any local configurations necessary to make all of this work.

   Install maven. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jtj-0yhox5s
   Optional: Install python.
2. Setup the repository in BitBucket to use as Maven repository

   1. Create a local folder e.g maven-repo with sub folders maven-repo\jars and maven-repo\repository
   2. Copy the jar files into maven-repo\jars.
   3. In order to install one of the jars into the repository use the maven command:

   `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId={jarOwner..more like group folder} -DartifactId={jarName} -Dversion={x.x.x} -Dfile={Path to the jar file in maven-repo\jars} -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -DlocalRepositoryPath=./repository  -DcreateChecksum=true`

   e.g 
   `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=GSON-2.2.4 -Dversion=2.2.4 -Dfile=C:\Development\maven-repo\jars\gson-2.2.4.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -DlocalRepositoryPath=./repository  -DcreateChecksum=true`

   *Optional*
       If there are many jars you can use installJars.py script(This script's owner is the creator of the guide I followed). In cmd: `python.exe installJars {jarsFolder_FullPath} {version}`
       But all the library installation will have the same version..so it could be considered as repository version and include the jar version in the jar name(artifactId).
       The script also produces a dependency file and the maven commands for all the libraries installation.

   4. Create a bitbucket PUBLIC repository with the same name as the local (maven-repo).
      Open the bitbucket project in SourceTree, then copy the content of the maven-repo of step 1 into the maven-repo folder which is linked with bitbucket.
      Commit and push.
      The path for each jar in bitbucket should be maven-repo/repository/{groupId}/{artifactId}/{version}/{artifactId+version}.jar
                                               e.g maven-repo/repository/com/mycompany/gson-2.2.4/1.0/gson-2.2.4-1.0.jar

      There is another step in the guide(@document top) creating a main dependency jar.. but was not needed to make it work.
3. Setup an IntelliJ project to reference the libraries in the repository for consistent builds

   In order to start a new IntelliJ project that uses gradle 
       Click File->New Project
       Choose Gradle from the list.
       Check 'create directories for empty content roots automatically' and make sure that 'User default gradle wrapper' is chosen.
       Click next.
       Name the project.
       Click finish.

   Under the root project directory there is build.gradle file.  In order to use  the custom repository, delete mavenCentral() from repository and add:

`repositories {
    maven {
       url 'https://bitbucket.org/{bitbucketUsername}/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/

  }
}`

Then in the same file define the library dependencies like this:

`dependencies{ 
    compile 'com.mycompany:gson-2.2.4:1.0'

  //compile '{groupId}:{artifactId}:{version}'    <--all these as defined in the installation maven commands.
    compile 'com.mycompany:license4j-1.6:1.0'
    compile 'com.mycompany:kendo-taglib-2015.1.429:1.0'
}`

Build the project. If libraries don't appear click Gradle tasks (from the left side list) and click the refresh button.

You can add the following lines in build.gradle in order to print the content of gradle cache.

```
task showMeCache << {
  configurations.compile.each { println it}
}
```